# Generic method to find largest in 2D array

Tags: java, generics, max, multidimensional-array

So guys I have to write a generic method to find the maximum element in a 2-D array then I have to test using integers, strings, and objects.

I'm a little sleep deprived so I apologize for what is probably a very very simple fix.

I have my generic method:

```
public class Generic {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T Max(T[][]stuff) {
        T max = stuff[0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j <stuff.length; i++)
                if (stuff[i][j].compareTo(max) > 0)
                    max = stuff[i][j];
        return max;
    }
}
```

and simply trying to test with integers first

```
public class GenericTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] myArray = { {0,1,2,3}, {3,2,1,0}, {3,5,6,1}, {3,8,3,4} };

        System.out.println(Generic.Max(myArray));
    }
}
```

Ok I fixed the previous error, dumb mistake, but yes now I am getting The method Max(T[][]) in the type Generic is not applicable for the arguments (int[][])

what would be the best fix for this problem?

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you need `Generic.Max(myArray)` or else you need to

```
import static Generic.Max;
```

at the top of `GenericTester.java`.

Generics will not work with primitive types, so `T` cannot be bound to `int`. Note, in particular, that `int` does not extend `Comparable<int>`. You will need to use an `Integer[][]` array instead of `int` and similarly for the other primitive types.

**EDIT** In addition to the above, your loops need some work. First, the increment on the inner loop is wrong (this is why you are seeing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`). Second, your code requires that the matrix is square and full (since you use `stuff.length` for the inner loop limit). Here's how I would write them (using [enhanced `for` loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) syntax):

```
public class Generic {
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T Max(T[][]stuff) {
        T max = stuff[0][0];
        for (T[] row : stuff) {
            for (T elt : row) {
                if (elt.compareTo(max) > 0) {
                    max = elt;
                }
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

For a truly general method, you would want to check that `stuff[0][0]` exists.

Comment: That is the *next* problem the OP will run into after he fixes the issue he is asking about.

Comment: @JasonC - assuming, of course, that `GenericTester` didn't `import static Generic.Max`.

Comment: That would have generated `The method Max(T[][]) in the type Generic is not applicable for the arguments (int[][])`.

Comment: I updated the code to fix what you guys pointed out and it fixed that error, but you guys are correct this is the error I am now getting. How would this be fixed? thaks

Comment: @user2745043 Ted Hopp explains that clearly in the second part of his answer here. You cannot bind `int` (or any primitive type) to a generic type, although you can use `Integer` instead.

Comment: @JasonC yes sorry I figured out after I asked it, but now I am getting a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4... any suggestions?

Comment: Your inner loop is in bad shape. You are incrementing `i` instead of `j` and you mean `stuff[i].length` not `stuff.length` in that loop... You need to do some troubleshooting and debugging on your own. I also suggest reading up on relevant language tutorials at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/.

Comment: @user2745043 - I added an analysis and some sample code to address the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Ok thanks so much that fixed it, but for future reference, what is 'elt'?

Comment: @user2745043 - It's the name I picked for the inner loop variable.